# d3 Increase radius of a particular circular node

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am new to d3.

Following is the link in which i want to increase the radius of the center node.

http://jsfiddle.net/k2NL5/81/

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.owner);
})


for(var counter in graph.nodes);
d3.select(node[0][counter]).attr("r",10);
```

EDIT:
Now it has become dynamic. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Change `.attr("r", 8)` to whatever radius you want to set.

Comment: It will change radius of all node, not center node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also vary radius dynamicly by json values like in your case

```
.attr("r", function(d){ return (d.application_name == 'paragon')?20:10; })
```

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k2NL5/82/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
d3.select(node[0][8]).attr("r",10);
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2NL5/80/

Comment: Size of node is static. Not able to change center radius if data are dynamic.

Comment: In Question its not mention about dynamic or static. You are giving opinion vote dude. :(

Comment: for(var counter in graph.nodes);
d3.select(node[0][counter]).attr("r",10);